# Интерфейс приложения

Tags: интерфейс, visual-studio, c++

Пожалуйста, помогите общей подсказкой.

Есть примитивное приложение, интерфейс которого содержит набор кнопок, каждая из которых открывает определенную web-страничку (используется елемент webBrowser MS Visual Studio, C++ ).

Проблема: количество кнопок, их названия и адрес, который они открывают, должен храниться в настроечном файле. И после его редактирования и перезапуска приложения, соответственно, интерфейс меняется.

Как это реализовать? Пожалуйста, подскажите, где можно об этом почитать, поскольку не получается правильно спросить у гугла.

Большое спасибо заранее.

Comment: @Andriy_abc, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Ответ зависит от того, какой UI-фреймворк вы используете.
Если MFC, вам придётся генерировать кнопки, их тексты и их позиции вручную, основываясь на данных файла с настройками.

[google "mfc add button to dialog"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mfc+add+button+to+dialog) -> [how to create a button dynamically in mfc dialog form](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/574317/howplustopluscreateplusaplusbuttonplusdynamicallyp)

Comment: Спасибо большое очень помогло, пожалуйста подскажите как привязать размер элемента webbrowser к размеру окна, для синхронного масштабирования? Еще раз большое спасибо.